# How can I code a combo box to display a list in a list box based on the selection in the combo box?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, combobox, listbox

I am trying to use the selection in the combo box to display a specific list in the listbox based on the combo box selection. I am using C#. I receive two types of errors, four of each, being one per if statement.

Here are the two error codes:

Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'

Here is an example of the code I have been working on, after fixing a few errors and mistakes I have narrowed it down to here from searching for solutions. I cannot find any definite solution to the errors I recieve.

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ComboBox1.Items.Add("W");
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("X");
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Y");
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Z");


        String var;
        var = ComboBox1.Text;


        List<String> WList = new List<String>(){"W1", "W2", "..."};

        List<String> XList = new List<String>(){"X1", "X2", "..."};

        List<String> YList = new List<String>(){"Y1", "Y2", "..."};

        List<String> ZList = new List<String>(){"Z1", "Z2", "..."};


        if (ComboBox1.SelectedItem="W")
        {
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = WList;
        }

        if(ComboBox1.SelectedItem="X")
        {
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = XList;
        }

        if(ComboBox1.SelectedItem="Y")
        {
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = YList;
        }

        if (ComboBox1.SelectedItem="Z")
        {
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = ZList;
        }

        else
        {
        ListBox1.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: You are adding items to the ComboBox as you are making a selection?  That makes no sense.  This looks weird: `var = ComboBox.Text;`  You aren't doing anything with your four lists.  DisplayMember is for the *Property* of your DataSource.

Comment: Perhaps you want to set the DataSource property not the DisplayMember. However what are those X,Y,Z and WItems? You have X,Y,Z and WList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you compare strings you need to use the `==` operator and not the assignment `=` operator!

Please change

```
if(ComboBox1.SelectedItem="W")
```

To:

```
if(ComboBox1.SelectedItem == "W")
```

I don't understand why you are adding W,X,Y,Z to you combobox item each time the user selects an item but to get the lists into your Listbox you should use the `DataSource` property like this:

```
if (ComboBox1.SelectedItem == "W")
{
    ListBox1.DataSource= WList;
}
```

2) Please remove this part of your code:

```
String var;
var = ComboBox.Text;
```

[var](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) is a keyword and should not be used as a name for variables! `ComboBox` is a class name and not the name of your instance `ComboBox1`. `ComboBox` does not have a static property `Text`! only the instance `ComboBox1` has it note the **1** in the name! please change it to

```
string temp = ComboBox1.Text;
```

3) you should declare the lists outside the scope of the `ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. Otherwise you create them unnecessarily each time new whenever you select an item in the combobox

Comment: Also, there's no reason for that string definition to be on two lines, it seems to try to access some static property `Text` on the `ComboBox` class instead of on a variable, and the string var is never even used later on.

Comment: @Nyerguds I just realized the same point and added the information

Comment: btw `ComboBox1.SelectedItem="W"` should be with `==` or he'll get the same mistake.

Comment: @CNuts Thank you , I have overseen this one. Is quite a lot of stuff wrong in the code... changed it

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't be adding new items to your combobox in the selection changed unless if you want to add new items each time the selection in the combobox changes. I don't think that's what you're trying to do. You should also prepare that list of string somewhere else than in the selection changed event.

So start by adding your combobox items and your `List<string>` where you initialize everything like in the Form1 constructor :

```
List<String> WList;

List<String> XList;

List<String> YList;

List<String> ZList;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.Items.Add("W");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("X");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Y");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Z");

    WList = new List<String>() { "W1", "W2", "..." };

    XList = new List<String>() { "X1", "X2", "..." };

    YList = new List<String>() { "Y1", "Y2", "..." };

    ZList = new List<String>() { "Z1", "Z2", "..." };
}
```

Also you're using `=` to compare the values that's why you're getting

> Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

You should be using `==` when you wanna verify if two values are equal.

Then in the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` all you need to do is verify which value is selected and adjust the `DataSource` and its better to use `else if` because you'll never have your `combobox` equal to two values at the same time:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "W")
    {
        listBox.DataSource= WList;
    }
    else if(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "X")
    {
        listBox.DataSource= XList;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Y")
    {
        listBox.DataSource= YList;
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Z")
    {
        listBox.DataSource= ZList;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure OP is using WPF ?

Comment: Ya hadn't realized it but hes probably using winforms. I'll edit it thanks. @MongZhu

Comment: @Confused No problem, I'm happy it helped.